# Flutter: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget, when using Expanded inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Below is the hierarchy of my Widgets. The `SingleChildScrollView` and `Expanded` were added simply because I wish to get the `RefreshIndicator` working.

```
Scaffold
  SingleChildScrollView
    Expanded
      RefreshIndicator
        Column
```

It was working until I upgrade my flutter recently and caused the following error **Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget**

I have did a search, the problem seems like because
`Expanded` widget can only reside in `Column`, `Row` or `Flex`

I put the expanded in any of the widgets above will results in either the refresh not working or another weird error.

Again, my main intention is to have my `RefreshIndicator` working inside a `Scaffold`.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you will add full code

Comment: Swapping `Expanded` and `SingleChildScrollView` should work fine.

Comment: @JahidulIslam Actually everything is working well without the ``Expanded``. The reason I need to add expanded is because I need the ``SingleChildScrollView`` to expand to the height of the entire page, instead of just a few rows that I have inside the ``Column``. The full page is 648 lines. I don't think it is a good idea to paste here.

Comment: you can use `Expanded` inside `Column` and the rest of my answer is ok. Have a try.

Comment: @JahidulIslam I replaced the ``Column`` with ``ListView`` and dropped the ``SingleChildScrollView`` and ``Expanded``. I don't know if there is any side effect, but things are working as expected now.

Comment: That's great you can do that, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter if you use `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded` then it will never work. And if you want to keep both widgets in your code then Wrap your `Expanded` with `Column` widget. Your `Column` widget should be parent widget of your `Expanded` widget , not in it's child widget.

Answer (score 0):

But you don't need to use the expend widget for the refresh indicator. Just try with the below code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: List.generate(50,  (f) => Text("Item $f")),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onRefresh: _refresh,
      ),
    )

//refresh function

Future<Null> _refresh() async{
    print('refreshing........');
  }
```